# Unbiased Estimator for $\log\left[\int p(x\mid z)p(z) \, dz\right]$

Tags: monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, logarithm, intractable-likelihood

The naive Monte Carlo estimator is an unbiased estimator for $\int p(x\mid z)p(z) \, dz$, is there a convenient unbiased estimator for $\log \left[\int p(x\mid z)p(z)\,dz \right]$

Comment: This practice of using the same symbol, in this case $p,$ to refer to various different functions in one expression is abominable. Unfortunately it sometimes appears even in the writings of otherwise respectable people. One could write $$ \int p_{X\,\mid\, Z\,=\,z} (x) p_Z(z) \, dz, $$ being careful that $X$ and $x$ have two different meanings and $Z$ and $z$ have two different meanings. That the execrable notation above can lead to errors and confusions and inabilities to see things deserves some attention. Maybe I'll write about it at greater length at some point. $\qquad$

Comment: While I don't disagree with the point you make in your complaint, and it's about a practice rather than any personal characteristic, nevertheless it might be better - particularly with a new contributor - to use slightly less strong terms, since it might be perceived as unwelcoming.

Comment: Close to all machine learning papers (from the relevant venues) today can be sufficiently described with said notation. Sufficiently here means, that the methods and proposed experiments can be reproduced to 100%.

Changing to the proposed notation would not add any *required* precision but unnecessary clutter.

Further, calling the way a whole community has chosen to note things "abominable" is a clear violation of the code of conduct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be shown that by using sufficiently large sample sizes for the MC approximation, a lower bound to the marginal log-likelihood is tightened. While this estimator is hence biased, in can serve the same practical purposes. It was shown in [1] that

$$
\log p(x) \ge \mathcal{L}_{K+1} \ge \mathcal{L}_{K} 
$$

for $\mathcal{L}_K = \mathbb E_{z_1, \ldots, z_K \sim q^K} \left[\log \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{p(x, z_k)}{q(z_k)}\right]$, where $q^K \equiv \underbrace{q \otimes q \otimes \cdots \otimes q}_{K times}$.

This also holds for $q(z) = p(z)$.

[1] Burda, Yuri, Roger Grosse, and Ruslan Salakhutdinov. "Importance weighted autoencoders." arXiv preprint arXiv:1509.00519 (2015).

Answer (score 5):

Path sampling is a way to evaluate the log integral by an unbiased estimator. Let us introduce a temperature index $0\le t\le 1$ and a sequence of conditional functions $p_t(x|z)$ such that
$$p_0(x|z)=1\qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad p_1(x|z)=p(x|z)$$
Then, if $$\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)=\int p_t(x|z)\,q(z)\text{d}z$$
\begin{align*}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \log(\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)) 
&= \frac{1}{\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)}\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}p_t(x|z)\,q(z)\text{d}z\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)}\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}p_t(x|z)\,q(z)\text{d}z\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathfrak{Z}_t(x)}\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\log(p_t(x|z))\,p_t(x|z)q(z)\text{d}z\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left.\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\log(p_t(x|Z))\right| X=x\right]\end{align*}
Therefore, since
$$\log(\mathfrak{Z}_1(x)/\mathfrak{Z}_0(x)) = \int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \log(\mathfrak{Z}_t(x))\,\text{d}t$$
and $\mathfrak{Z}_0(x)=1$, a remarkable identity is that
$$\log(\mathfrak{Z}_1(x))=\log\left\{\int p(x|z) q(z)\text{d}z\right\}=\int_0^1  \mathbb{E}\left[\left.\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\log(p_t(x|Z))\right| X=x\right]\,\text{d}t$$
Hence, assuming simulations $z_i=\zeta(x,t,\epsilon_i)$ ($i=1,\ldots,I$) from $$q(z|x)=\frac{q(z) p(x|z)}{\mathfrak{Z}_1(x))}$$ are available (e.g. by MCMC), an unbiased estimator of $\log(\mathfrak{Z}_1(x))$ is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{I}\sum_{i=1}^I\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\log(p_t(x|\zeta(x,t,\epsilon_i)))\,\text{d}t$$

Answer (score 2):

The Monte Carlo estimator using $n$ samples of

$$l = \int p(x \mid z) g(z) dz = E(p(x \mid Z))$$

with $Z\sim g$ is

$$\hat l_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i = 1}p(x\mid Z_i) \qquad Z_i\sim g$$

Following [Durbin and Koopman
(1997)](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/84.3.669), the error of the log
marginal likelihood is given by

$$\begin{align*}
\log\hat l_n - \log l
  &= \log\left(1 + \frac{\hat l_n - l}{l}\right) \\
  &= \frac{\hat l_n - l}{l}
    - \frac 12\left(\frac{\hat l_n - l}{l}\right)^2 +
    O\left(\left(\frac{\hat l_n - l}{l}\right)^3\right)
\end{align*}$$

implying that the bias is

$$
E(\log\hat l_n) =  \log l
  - \frac 12\frac{E\left((\hat l_n - l)^2\right)}{l^2} +
    O\left(\frac{E\left((\hat l_n - l)^3\right)}{l^3}\right)
$$

Thus, the bias is approximately proportional to the variance
of the estimated log-likelihood using the delta method and
that $E(\hat l_n) =l$.
The bias corrected version from Durbin and Koopman (1997) is
therefor

$$
\log\hat l_n + \frac 12 \frac{\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat l_n)}{\hat l_n^2}
$$

where $\widehat{\text{Var}}$ is the estimated variance. That is,

$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat l_n) = \frac 1{n(n -1)} \sum_{i = 1}^n\left(p(x\mid Z_i) - \hat l_n\right)^2.$$

The adjusted estimator is convenient as we already have all the quantities we need from the standard Monte Carlo estimator.
The above can also be
extended to importance sampling. Pick an importance distribution with density $h$ with the same support as $g$. Then replace $p(x\mid Z_i)$ in $\hat l_n$ (and the variance estimate) with

$$
\frac{p(x\mid Z_i)g(Z_i)}{h(Z_i)}
$$

and sample $Z_i\sim h$.

### Example

Take $g(z) = \phi(z)$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal
distribution's density function and

$$
p(x\mid z) = \Phi(0.5 + z)\Phi(-0.25 - z)
$$

where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution's cumulative density function. In this case $l$ is the bivariate normal CDF integrated up to 0.5 and -0.25 with covariance matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

which can be computed to floating point precision which makes this example nice.

A small simulation study investigating the bias of the adjusted and unadjusted Monte Carlo estimator as a function of the sample size is run below.

```r
# the true value of l
truth <- mvtnorm::pmvnorm(
  upper = c(.5, -.25), sigma = matrix(c(2, -1, -1, 2), 2))

n_reps <- 100000L # the number of replications
# the sample sizes
n_samples <- seq(log(10), log(1000), length.out = 40) |> exp() |> floor()

# compute the estimates
set.seed(1)
ests <- sapply(n_samples, \(n_samp){
  smps <- matrix(rnorm(n_samp * n_reps), n_samp)
  weight <- pnorm(.5 + smps) * pnorm(-0.25 - smps)
  rbind(Estimate = colMeans(weight), Var = apply(weight, 2L, var) / n_samp)
}, simplify = "array")

# compute the bias estimates
err_unadjusted <- log(ests["Estimate", , ]) - log(truth)
bias_ests_unadjusted <- colMeans(err_unadjusted)
err_adjusted <- 
  log(ests["Estimate", , ]) + ests["Var", , ] / (2 * ests["Estimate", , ]^2) - 
  log(truth)
bias_ests_adjusted <- colMeans(err_adjusted)

# plot the bias estimates versus the sample size
ylim <- range(bias_ests_unadjusted, bias_ests_adjusted)
par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 1))
plot(n_samples, bias_ests_unadjusted, pch = 16, bty = "l", ylim = ylim,
     ylab = "Bias estimate (unadjusted)", xlab = "Sample size", log = "x")
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
plot(n_samples, bias_ests_adjusted, pch = 16, bty = "l", ylim = ylim,
     ylab = "Bias estimate (adjusted)", xlab = "Sample size", log = "x")
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

[image]

The plots show that the adjusted estimator seems to be unbiased but the standard Monte Carlo estimator is downward biased consistent with [the answer by bayerj](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384452/81865). However, the bias of the latter gets smaller as the number of samples is increased also consistent with the answer by bayerj.

A side note, the plot above shows that the variance of the log-likelihood estimator is about $2 \cdot 0.012$ in the worst case when we use $n = 10$ samples. Thus,
the standard error of the estimator is $\sqrt{2 \cdot 0.012} = 0.125$. Hence, a bias of $0.012$ may not be the main concern.